# Insert values into new dataset from exisisting dataset

Tags: for-loop, dataset, vb.net-2010

Am using vb.net.Having dataset contain column name as phone .it contain set of phone number. i want to add 0 to each phone number and store it in another dataset.

### my code

```
cmd = New OracleCommand("select substr(PHONE,-10)as PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('" + TextBox1.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('" + TextBox2.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  region not in('TNP')", cn)
ada = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
ada.Fill(ds, "reports.renewal_contact_t ")
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
ds1 = ds.Clone()
For Each q In ds.Tables(0).Rows
   phone = z + q("PHONE").ToString
   For Each q1 In ds1.Tables(0).Rows
      q1("PHONE") = phone
   Next
Next
```

my problem is am not getting values in ds1.

Please help me to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
cmd = New OracleCommand("select substr(PHONE,-10)as PHONE from  reports.renewal_contact_t where run_date=to_date('" + TextBox1.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  EXP_DATE =to_date('" + TextBox2.Text + "','mm/dd/yyyy') and  region not in('TNP')", cn)
ada = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
ada.Fill(ds, "reports.renewal_contact_t ")
Dim ds1 As New DataSet
ds1 = ds.Copy()

For Each q In ds1.Tables(0).Rows
    q("PHONE") = "0" + q("PHONE").ToString
Next
```